# How to prevent tinyMCE from modifying image URLs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, imageurl

I have a problem with tinyMCE and Image URLs in rails. I inserted the image with this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/fold1/fold2/fold3/2010/name.png
```

and the image is properly inserted. But when I right-click on the image and select *insert/edit image*, there is this (instead of the URL I pasted):

```
../../../fold2/fold3/2010/name.png
```

Since I use this image on more pages, this relative URLs doesn't work for me. I want to set that tinyMCE doesn't modify the URL at all. The URL should be exactly the same, as I write it!

After i did some digging, I believe I should set **convert_urls : false** inside **tinyMCE.init**. Am I right? But I am not able to set this.

I looked for *tinyMCE.init* function inside my *rails* project with **grep -r "tinyMCE.init" *** and I found one call of init function inside **public/javascripts/tiny_mce/plugins/fullscreen/fullscreen.htm** file. The call of init function looks like:

```
tinyMCE.init(settings)
```

above the call there is this code, which set the *settings*:

```
            // Set options
            delete settings.id;
            settings['mode'] = 'exact';
            settings['elements'] = 'fullscreenarea';
            settings['add_unload_trigger'] = false;
            settings['ask'] = false;
            //     settings['document_base_url'] = window.opener.tinyMCE.activeEditor.documentBaseURI.getURI();
            settings['fullscreen_is_enabled'] = true;
            settings['fullscreen_editor_id'] = oeID;
            settings['theme_advanced_resizing'] = false;
            settings['strict_loading_mode'] = true;

            //I ADDED THIS TWO LINES
            settings['convert_urls'] = false;
            settings['relative_urls'] = false;
```

As you can see I commented out the line with 'document_base_url' and added the last two lines. But this doesn't work. The URLs are stil modifying when I insert them. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
settings['remove_script_host'] = false;
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. Strange, as I read the documentation, this would have to work. I will probably edit links in the DB :(

Answer (score 1):

This page might help you to decide what url setting to choose: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php